# Why is ReadWriteLockSlim so slow? // Is this custom implementation safe?

Tags: c#, multithreading

I wrote a small database where the usage is 95% reads. I was looking for bottlenecks and out of curiosity wanted to compare the speeds of the available locking mechanisms:

In a purely single-threaded environment I get this result with only read requests:

no lock: 1%
spinlock: 16%
rwLock: 60%
of ticks to complete.

I am aware that RWLock will look a lot better in a multi-threaded environment but I don't quite comprehend why it takes so much more time when just aquiring a lock for reading?

I wrote a small custom RW-lock and it performs 3 times better than rwLock at 20% of total ticks.

Here's the code:

```
 class FastRWLock
{
    private int _readers = 0;
    private bool _isWriting = false;
    private object _spinLock = new object();

    private AutoResetEvent _notifier = new AutoResetEvent(false);
    private bool needsNotify = false;

    public void AquireReaderLock() {

        if (_isWriting) {
            lock (_spinLock) {

            }
        }
        _readers++;
    }

    public void ExecuteWrite(Action a)  {
        if (_isWriting) {
            lock (_spinLock) {//Only ends up here if another writer has already entered the following spinlock, thus, this one wont exite here until the previous write is done

            }
        }
        try
        {
            _isWriting = true;
            lock (_spinLock)//intention to write made public, idling until previous readers, that enqueued when another writeaction was active
            {//probable deadlock?
                if (_readers > 0) {
                    needsNotify = true;
                _notifier.WaitOne();
                    needsNotify = false;
                   }
                a.Invoke();
            }
        }
        finally {
            _isWriting = false;
        }
    }

    public void ReleaseReaderLock() {
        _readers--;
        if (_readers < 1 && needsNotify) {
            _notifier.Set();
        }
    }

}
```

Is this a viable solution or am I risking a deadlock? If not, what else is the standard RWLock doing that makes it perform so much worse?

Comment: Looks like plenty of races/broken contracts here. E.g. in `ExecuteWrite`, you check `_readers` which may be greater than 0. Before you get a chance to set `needsNotify` to true, a reader completely executes `ReleaseReaderLock`. Your writer is now blocked waiting for a `Set` that will never get called.

Comment: Yes, I'd expect your code to be faster, considering that it doesn't synchronize access to shared fields like `_isWriting` and `_readers` at all. No, this implementation is definitely not safe. If you're interested in the implementation, why not [read the source](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Core/system/threading/ReaderWriterLockSlim/ReaderWriterLockSlim.cs)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to be using volatile reads and writes of your variables that are outside of `lock` blocks, you could be reading cached values.

Also you can't do `_readers--` or `_readers++` in a multi-threaded environment outside of a `lock` block. You will need to use [`Interlocked.Increment`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd78zt0c(v=vs.110).aspx) and [`Interlocked.Decrement`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1z4b2e5y(v=vs.110).aspx)

There may be other problems, but those where the first to major ones that jumped out at me.

If you fixed the problems in your code I would bet you would see a lot less of a "performance gain" because I think the performance gain is caused by bugs in your code that makes your version not reliable to use. Writing locking primitives is very hard to do correctly. I would recommend trying to use the built in classes where possible.

Comment: Ah yes I forgot about that. Just tried it out and it does impact performance significantly.